# In search of an algorithm for sorting collection in nodes to satisfy a layout constraint

Tags: algorithm, topology

Firstly, I apologize for the poor title; I cannot think of a good name for this algorithm.

I have an ordered list of *stages*. Each stage has a *cast* of *characters*, unordered. Characters can occur in multiple stages.

A *crossing* occurs when two consecutive stages cannot have their casts concatenated, with overlap allowed where it would unify the same character on both casts, in a way that leaves a character duplicated in the concatenation. Or, informally, a crossing is when a character would need to be at two different spots at once in a line-up of the combined casts. In code:

```py
uncrossed = [D, F], [N, V, S]
overlap = [D, F, V], [V, N, S]
crossed = [D, V, F], [N, V, S]
```

In the first example, V isn't with D and F, so there aren't any crossings. In the second example, V is with D and F and then with N and S, but this isn't a problem because the ordering permits (with overlap) a crossing-less concatenation. On the third example, though, the ordering forces a crossing.

For my purposes, crossings can occur on non-consecutive stages as if characters did not actually stray from their previous order in the cast when they are not "on-stage."

I would like to order each stage's cast such that there are as few crossings as possible, understanding that it is definitely possible to have situations where crossings are inevitable. An example series which requires crossings:

```py
required = [A, B], [B, C], [A, C], [A, B]
```

This all sounds very abstract and silly, so I'll provide a concrete example of a human solving this algorithm for a purpose similar to mine: http://xkcd.com/657/ In this case, the constraint is deliberately ignored for aesthetic purposes, but it's still possible to get a visual idea of what I'm talking about.

I already have some crude ideas for how to solve this, but nothing affordable, and I'm wondering if this is isomorphic to some problem already covered in the literature. It sounds vaguely topological as well.

Since people asked, this algorithm appears to be key to automatically generating pretty timelines for storyboards of characters in stories, and that's what I'm intending to use it for.

Comment: Please provide an example of what *you* are looking for.  The cartoon you are linking to bears no apparent relationship to your description.   In particular it's not at all obvious what one of your "nodes" is supposed to be in these illustrations.  The closest thing might be the barely discernible "events" in the pictures, but they are not at all laid out "horizontally".  It may be "*possible to get an idea of what I'm talking about*" by looking at it, but it's far from likely.

Comment: Is there ever a case where a member appears in node A and node C but not node B, so you need a line connecting A to C and skipping B? If not, there's no reason for lines to ever cross as long as you keep the members in the same order each time.

Comment: This does sound topological and I would guess that a general optimal solution to this particular problem is unknown and pretty hard.  If you manage to hack something ad-hoc together that works reasonably well, that might be the best you can do.  (Of course you could brute-force an exhaustive search solution for a particular input, and this may not be so bad either since it doesn't sound like you need a real-time solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but I think maybe a more precise or even more correct formulation of what you are looking for:

There is a set, call it `C`, of *characters*, and there is a finite ordered sequence `S_1, ... S_n` of *scenes*, where a *scene* is a set consisting of some of the characters.  Characters may (and typically do) appear in multiple scenes.

I'd like to phrase your desired outcome in a slightly different way from how you phrased it, because I think it makes it clearer how one may search for a solution (or at least, it makes it totally clear how to brute-force a solution):

The output of our algorithm is a sequence of arrangements of the characters.  An *arrangement* of the characters is just a permutation of the ordered tuple `[c_1, ... c_m]`, where the `c_i` are the characters, and there are `m` of them in total, so `C = {c_1, ..., c_m}`.  We want `n` arrangements in total, call them `A_1, ..., A_n`, one per scene.

What arrangement `A_n` corresponds to is the top-to-bottom ordering of the characters in your storyboard, during scene `n`, in the following sense: draw a vertical line through your storyboard passing through scene `n`.  This line should hit the characters' life-lines in the order specified by `A_n`.

We require the following property of our arrangements: given scene `S_n`, the arrangement `A_n` needs to put the characters contained in `S_n` into a contiguous chunk, in the following sense: suppose that `S_n = {c_2, c_3, c_5}`.  Then `A_n` may yield `[c_1, c_4, c_2, c_3, c_5]`, but may not yield `[c_2, c_1, c_3, c_4, c_5]`.  This is because you don't want an errant character "cutting through" the scene in the storyboard.

We hope to minimize the number of "crossings."  Here, crossings are easy to define: the number of crossings between `A_i` and `A_(i+1)` is exactly equal to the number of *transpositions of adjacent characters* required to go from permutation `A_i` to permutation `A_(i+1)`.

---

I haven't given you an answer, but I think that given the above setup, a brute-force approach isn't too hard to code up, and will give you an answer overnight without a problem, if the storyboard isn't too big.

I think that if you posted this problem on MathOverflow, you could possibly get someone interested in it.  Or maybe it has been solved, who knows?

Comment: Nice formalism. Looks right to me. This was going to be for hundreds (maybe thousands at worst) of elements, and I was going to hopefully only generate them once every hour or so at worst. Guess I'll sleep on it some more.

Comment: A partner and I have talked about this, and with a sufficiently well-organized data structure, we have a sketch of a linear-time solution. I will come back here and reply once I'm confident of our approach. In the meantime, accepting for karma.

Comment: @Corbin Cool, thanks.  I'm curious to know what the linear-time version of this is!